# Replace multiple substrings with blanks in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, regex, replace, substring

I have a situation where I want to replace part of a string with blanks. For example, my columns looks something like this:

```
user_comment
it was a good day but nothing in particular happened
nothing specific happening today
no comments. all ok
not much happening really, it will be fine
```

and the desired outcome I want is:

```
user_comment_clean
it was a good day but happened
happening today
all ok
it will be fine
```

Essentially I would like to remove parts of strings as shown above such as "nothing in particular" , nothing specific" , "no comment" and "not much happening really"

and I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
def remove_no_comments(text):
   text = re.sub(r"^nothing in particular", ' ', text)
   text = re.sub(r"^nothing specific", ' ', text)
   text = re.sub(r"^no comment", ' ', text)
   text = re.sub(r"^not much happening really", ' ', text)
   text = text.lower()
   return text
df['user_comments_clean] = df['user_comments_clean].astype(str).apply(remove_no_comments)
```

But while using this, it is making my other user inputs as nan and I am really not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any possible solutions to resolve this?

Comment: *such as* or *exactly* "nothing in particular" , nothing specific" , "no comment" and "not much happening really"? Or is there a general formula for identifying these?

Comment: The idea is that when a user provides such words or combination of words, it doesn't add any value to my analysis but in general there is no specific formula to identify this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `str.replace()` along with a regex alternation:

```py
terms = ["nothing in particular", "nothing specific", "no comment", "not much happening really"]
regex = r'^(?:' + r'|'.join(terms) + r')\b\s*'
df["user_comment_clean"] = df["user_comment"].str.replace(regex, '', regex=True)
```

Comment: worked well. Thanks much but what could be wrong in the solution that I have provided. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, your series of replacements should basically be doing the same thing as the alternation in my answer.  I don't know why it isn't working.  It could have something to do with the `apply()` call.

Comment: Could be a possibility .Thanks for your answer :) One last thing. What if I have to completely make these strings as blank and not just a part of it? So whenever such term combinations are found, just make that entire string blank. Any idea around that?

Comment: Yes, just match on: `regex = r'.*\b(?:' + r'|'.join(terms) + r')\b.*'` and replace with empty string.

Comment: Totally forgot to add that